# How to extract data from HTTP header in C?

Tags: c, http-headers, winsock

Today I am asking how to extract the data section from the received buffer in my `recv()` in C (not C++).

I just need some suggestions, how would I get

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT\r\n
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)\r\n
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT\r\n
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"\r\n
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
Content-Length: 131\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
\r\n

<html>
<head>
<title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```

The  part of the above header? It is stored in my buffer, I specifically just want to dissect the data (the source code of the page). Any ideas?

Comment: That is quite a lot to answer to.

Comment: So you just want to strip the header? If I were you I would introspect the data and try to infere the best strategy for the task.

Comment: Find `<html>` and discard everything before that?

Comment: maybe easiest way is to find the double \r\n, but you must be aware that the data may be chunked or deflate compressed, so parsing the response header can't be skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header ends with `\r\n\r\n`. If the whole response is in the receive buffer and you put a `'\0'` at the end of the response, then you can use the following code to find the start of the data section

```
char *data = strstr( buffer, "\r\n\r\n" );
if ( data != NULL )
{ 
    data += 4;
    // do something with the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually parse the data in order to know where the headers end and the message data begins, and where the message data ends.  The headers end with a `\r\n\r\n` (`CRLF`+`CRLF`, `0x0D 0x0A 0x0D 0x0A`) byte sequence.  So you have to keep reading until you encounter that terminator.  Then you have to parse the headers to know how the rest of the message is *encoded* and how it is *terminated*.  Refer to [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) for the rules.  That will tell you **HOW** to read the remaining data and **WHEN** to stop reading it.  The data might be chunked or compressed or self-terminating.  The `Content-Type` and `Transfer-Encoding` headers tell you how to interpret the message data.

In your particular example, after reading the headers, per Section 4.4 you would retrieve the value of the `Content-Length` header and then read exactly 131 bytes, stop reading, and close the socket because of the `Connection: close` header.  You would then retreive the value of the `Content-Type` header and know that the data is UTF-8 encoded HTML and process it accordingly.

See the pseudo-code I posted in an earlier answer:

[Receiving Chunked HTTP Data With Winsock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234357/65863)