# GET HTTP Request in C (Message Body)

Tags: c, character-encoding, http

I make a GET request with C in the following code:

```
   char buffer[1024] =
        "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: example.com\r\n"
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
        "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n"
        "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0\r\n"
        "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
        "Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n";

   size_t buffer_len = sizeof(buffer) - 1;

   /* Send message to the server */
   n = write(sockfd, buffer, buffer_len);

   /* Now read server response */
   bzero(buffer, strlen(buffer));
   n = read(sockfd, buffer, buffer_len);

   /* Display result */
   printf("%s\n",buffer);
   return 0;
```

Properly respond:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Sep 2016 17:20:48 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 6695
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

�
```

Except for the last line which should be Message Body,
instead of html content It appears only a symbol �, Does anyone know where can be the problem?

Comment: How big is `buffer`? Looks like you need to read at least 7000 characters from the server. You may need to call `read` a few times.

Comment: I also recommend taking a look in Wireshark so you can see exactly what is being sent,,, both using your code and a browser or netcat (a known working client) to see if there are any discrepancies.

Comment: Note `Content-Encoding: gzip` in the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You told the server that you are willing to accept a compressed response (see `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`), so the server actually sent you a gzip-compressed response (see `Content-Encoding: gzip`).  Your code does not actually support decompression (you can use the [zlib library](http://www.zlib.net) for that), so you need to remove `Accept-Encoding` from your request header. Then you will get a response with a message body that is not compressed.

Comment: Now displays plain text, and indeed it is not the whole page

Comment: @IsabelCariod: Your code is not attempting to process the response headers **at all**.  You need to process the headers, they tell you how the response is encoded, and thus how it must be read. Pay attention to the `Content-Length` and `Transfer-Encoding` headers to know *how many* bytes to expect, and *how* to read the bytes. [Read RFC 2616 Section 4.4 Message Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for more details, and see this [pseudo-code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7234357/65863) for the kind of reading logic you need to implement in your code.