# How to write binary data received with recv() to file

Tags: c, sockets, http, get, recv

I want to save everything received with GET request to file with this command:

```
./client http://example.com/1.jpg > image.jpg
```

My `recv_buf` is 2000 bytes.

```
// Generate HTTP request
sprintf(send_buf, "%s %s %s%s %s%s", "GET", path, "HTTP/1.1\r\n", 
                                "HOST:", hostname, "\r\n\r\n");

send_len = strlen(send_buf); //length of request to send
bytes_send = send(sockfd, send_buf, send_len, 0);

if (bytes_send <= 0)
{
    perror("nothing sended\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Bytes send: %d\nSended message: %s\n", bytes_send, send_buf);

// receive data

do {
    bytes_recv = recv(sockfd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0);

    if (bytes_recv <= 0) 
    {
        perror("connection closed or error");
        close(sockfd);
        freeaddrinfo(results);
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bytes_recv);

    //write(1, recv_buf, bytes_recv);

} while (bytes_recv > 0);
```

I am so far that I can receive data till the end, but I don't know how to combine all the "packages" to one buffer in correct order and then save it to file as binary data (image).

Output is:

```
./client https://example.com/1.jpg
Bytes received: 2000
Bytes received: 1792
Bytes received: 2000
Bytes received: 1792
Bytes received: 639
connection closed or error: Success
```

Comment: fopen() the file, after the recv() success, fwrite() bytes_recv bytes from the recv_buf, fclose() when the recv() loop exits because 0 bytes received.  It's that simple.

Comment: where `write(1, recv_buf, bytes_recv);` is commented, using `fwrite(recv_buf, bytes_recv,1,fhandle)` should do the trick (open fhandle in binary mode)

Comment: Ok thx it worked but how can I save this binary data to single array?Because I want then separate the header and body content and save it to image.jpg?

Comment: You don't want to use an array - you want to dynamically allocate memory to store the response and expand it as you receive more of it

Comment: Ok then lets say, I know the size of the body content and I've allocated enough memory then how can store all the response there (all this packages in correct order)?

Comment: Parsing an HTTP header would be another question, and I would be amazed if there are no duplicates.

Comment: @Dmitry: you are going about this all wrong.  You don't need to save the entire response to a single array at all. Your code is not even implementing the HTTP protocol correctly to begin with. Start by fixing that. Then you would be able to receive just the HTTP headers, and then parse the headers to know how to read the remaining body data so you can write it to file (or to stdout, in the case of your `> image.jpg` example). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7234357/65863

Answer (score 0):

You can use [realloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) and `memcpy` as follows:

```
unsigned char* buf = 0;
int bufsize = 0;
do {
    bytes_recv = recv(sockfd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0);
    if (bytes_recv <= 0) 
    {
        perror("connection closed or error");
        close(sockfd);
        freeaddrinfo(results);
        exit(0);
    }

    buf = realloc(buf, bufsize + bytes_recv);
    memcpy(buf + bufsize, recv_buf, bytes_recv);
    bufsize += bytes_recv;

} while (bytes_recv > 0);
```

`buf` will not contain `bufsize` bytes which has been read. Or write to the file and use `malloc` and read that file again.